# Is there a resource to tell you if an airport requires going through immigration for a connecting flight?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, india, mexico

I recently went from US to Costa Rica through Mexico City and was required to go through immigration in Mexico. This took over 2 hours and I barely made it on my other flight. Others in the line I overheard missed theirs. Not to mention it's painfully annoying!

Previously, I went from UK to Thailand through Delhi and didn't have to do this (only had to re-do security check).

Has anyone anywhere compiled a list of which airports make you do this? It seems to happen if you enter and stay within Schengen area ([Going through migration at connecting flight airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103828/going-through-migration-at-connecting-flight-airport)) and I also found this thread from 2 years ago http://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1339401 Would be great to have an up to date list, so travellers could choose their flights accordingly.

Comment: Schengen airports typically do *not* require travelers to go through passport controls when they are transferring from one external flight to another.  They do so when one of the flights is an internal Schengen flight and the other is not.  The traveler in the question you linked to had to go through immigration in Frankfurt because the next flight was to Amsterdam -- effectively a "domestic" flight within the Schengen area.

Comment: Good to know! I've corrected the post to specify.

Comment: "It seems to happen when you enter and stay within the Schengen area": it happens when you enter and stay within *any* country.  There's no country that would allow someone to transfer from an international to a domestic flight without clearing immigration.  The Schengen area is only odd here because it's a single territory for the purpose of passport control that comprises multiple countries.

Comment: This is awful broad. Sometimes it depends on which terminals you're flying to in an airport.

Comment: I guess Timatic is a good enough resource for this.

Comment: @ phoog arrgh it's hard to concisely explain..I meant how you can fly through Frankfurt to Milan and not realize you'll do your immigration check in Frankfurt and miss your connection. Since as you said the Schengen area is a little odd and counts as one territory. 

@ Roddy do you mean like domestic vs international terminals?

@ Burhan hmm, looks like it's subscription/1 month trial only :/

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, where is the reliable Timatic online one can use?

Comment: Just Google "Emirates visa requirements" and it will lead you to a search page that queries timatic. Subscription is only for travel providers.

Answer (score 3):

I can only comment on the countries I know or about which I have been advised.

Canada does, but it's a brief check.  The USA certainly does.  Another poster (below) advises that South Africa and the UK do checks, although the UK one is a quick one.

Comment: To add on to this, the UK has a quick check when transiting for citizens of some countries. South Africa has a check as well and immigration also stamps your passport.